# Flutter - TextFormField validator is not working in TabBarView

Tags: flutter, dart

I need some required values to submit.

I'm using TabBarView to view different sections.

Here's my code.

**add_products_screen.dart**

```dart
    class _AddProductScreenState extends State<AddProductScreen> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        final formkey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
    
        return Form(
          key: formkey,
          child: DefaultTabController(
            length: 2,
            initialIndex: 0,
            child: Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(
                title: const Text('Add Products'),
                bottom: const TabBar(
                  isScrollable: true,
                  indicator: UnderlineTabIndicator(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                      width: 4,
                      color: Colors.deepOrange,
                    ),
                  ),
                  tabs: [
                    Tab(child: Text('General')),
                    Tab(child: Text('Attributes')),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              drawer: const CustomDrawer(),
              body: const TabBarView(
                children: [
                  GeneralTab(),
                  AttributeTab(),
                ],
              ),
              persistentFooterButtons: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                        child: ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            if (formkey.currentState!.validate()) {}
                          },
                          child: const Text('Save Product'),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

**form_field_input.dart**

```dart
    class FormFieldInput extends StatelessWidget {
      final String? label;
      final void Function(String)? onChanged;
    
      const FormFieldInput({
        Key? key,
        this.label,
        this.onChanged,
      }) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return TextFormField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            label: Text(label!),
          ),
          validator: (value) {
            if (value!.isEmpty) {
              return '$label is required';
            }
            return null;
          },
          onChanged: onChanged,
        );
      }
    }
```

**general_tab.dart**

```dart
    class _GeneralTabState extends State<GeneralTab>
        with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
      @override
      bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        super.build(context);
    
        return Consumer<ProductProvider>(
          builder: (context, provider, child) {
            return ListView(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
              children: [
                FormFieldInput(
                  label: 'Product Name',
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    provider.getFormData(productName: value);
                  },
                ),
                FormFieldInput(
                  label: 'Description',
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    provider.getFormData(description: value);
                  },
                ),
              ],
            );
          },
        );
      }
    }
```

**attributes_tab.dart**

```dart
    class _AttributeTabState extends State<AttributeTab>
        with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
      @override
      bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        super.build(context);
    
        return Consumer<ProductProvider>(
          builder: (context, provider, _) {
            return ListView(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
              children: [
                FormFieldInput(
                  label: 'Brand',
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    provider.getFormData(brand: value);
                  },
                ),
                FormFieldInput(
                  label: 'Remarks',
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    provider.getFormData(remarks: value);
                  },
                ),
              ],
            );
          },
        );
      }
    }
```

My error is when I pressed save product button validator is showing only the 1st tab textformfields.
2nd tab textformfields validators are only showing when I go to that tab.
Otherwise, it won't show.

Here are some screenshots.

*Before I go to 2nd tab and press save product button*

[image]
[image]

*After I go to 2nd tab and press save product button*

[image]
[image]

---

### How do I solve this error?

Answer (score 1):

A form with a key will validate all of its children.

In your first case `General` tab alone created so those two `Formfileds` are the children of the `Form`.

But in your second case as you have opened the attributes tab, both the General and Attributes tab is loaded and now all 4 Form Fields are children of the Form.

So,

Wrap the `general_tab.dart` and `attributes_tab.dart` with individual `Form` widget with seperate form key.

Then validate them alone with their keys.

Comment: You mean wrap both **general_tab** and **attributes_tab** with form and give a key named `formKey` and keep the form in **add_products**?

Comment: Create two seprate form keys and use it in general and attributes with seperate form widget

Comment: I did this in **add_products_screen.dart** file.

Comment: `Form(key: key1, child: GeneralTab()),` and `Form(key: key1, child: AttributeTab()),` I wrapped these two widgets with Form and added seperate keys. Then it's working fine and thank you.

Comment: If its solved, Then accept and vote the answer. Will help others.